# python IndexErrorの対処法

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Raspberry Piでservoモーターを動かしたいと思っています。
以下のコードを動かすとエラーが出ました。

```
import wirignpi
import sys
param  = sys.argv   #コマンドライン引数を格納したリストの取得コード
if( -90<=int(param[1]) and int(param[1])<=90 ):
     set_degree = int(param[1]) #入力された値を配列
     print(set_degree)           #値をコマンドラインで表示
else:
     print("please input -90~90 degree\n")
```

以下のエラー文が出されました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "servo.py", line 13, in <module>
　　 if( -90<=int(param[1]) and int(param[1])<=90 ):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

どのように対応すればよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

追伸1:
「引数の数」をチェックしてみました。

```
import sys

args = sys.argv
arglen = len(args)

print(arglen)
print(args)
print(args[1])
print(args[2])
print(args[3])
quit()
```

実効してみると以下の反応でした。

```
$python3 a.py a b c
4
['a.py', 'a', 'b', 'c']
a
b
c
```

追伸2:
エラーの原因が分かりました。
コマンドラインに引数を入れるのを忘れていました。

```
$sudo python3 servo.py
```

ではなく、

```
$sudo python3 servo.py 45
```

とすべきでした。
ご協力ありがとうございます。

Comment: 実際にはプログラム自身(この場合は python スクリプト)が sys.argv[0] になりますので、`if (len(param) > 1) and (-90<=int(param[1]) and int(param[1])<=90 )` などとする必要があります。また、整数値以外の文字列を指定してしまうとエラーになりますので、その対応も必要になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに整数値以外の文字列エラーの対応の記述も必要ですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

引数を指定せずに実行した場合に`param[1]`の箇所で"index out of range"エラーが発生しているのだと思います。
事前に「引数の数」をチェックしてみてはどうでしょうか？

```
import sys
argvs = sys.argv
argc = len(argvs) # 引数の個数

if (argc != 1):
    print 'Usage: # python %s degree' % argvs[0]
    quit()
```